# How to hide webchat icon after user logout angular cognigy

Tags: angular, web-chat

I call initWebchat from webChatService after user login but I want to remove webChatIcon after user logout too, right now after user logout webChat icon still showing Here's the service that I create

`declare const initWebchat: any;

```
export class WebChatService {enter code here
  constructor(private readonly $sessionStorage: SessionStorageService) {}
  initWebchat() {
    initWebchat('https://endpoint-trial.cognigy.ai/xxxx', {
      sessionId: "'" + this.$sessionStorage.retrieve('sessionID') + "'",
      settings: {
        title: 'Test Title',
        inputPlaceholder: 'Please reply here',
        getStartedText: 'Hello Faii',
      },
    }).then((webchat) => {
      webchat.registerAnalyticsService((event) => {
   ....
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

support team sent me the solution in this link

const rootWebChat = document.querySelector('.webchat-root') as HTMLElement;

rootWebChat.style.display = 'none';

https://codesandbox.io/s/local-persistent-history-forked-zyxqz?file=/index.html:904-922